# Compare 2 sha512 hash passed as input in python

Tags: python, hash, comparison, sha512

I have 2 hashes which i need to compare.1 is coming from an API, other i have calculated internally 
I am aware that 2 `sha512` can be compared using

```
input1.digest() == input2.digest()
```

where both inputs are `sha512` hash.My problem here is that since i am getting 1 of them from an API, it is of `string` format and strings don't have `digest` :

> *** AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'digest'

I thought this would work :

```
if(calculated_hash != input_hash):
    return False
return True
```

how hash is getting generated internally for one of the test cases:

```
hash_val = sha512(parameters.encode('utf-8') + salt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

But since hash is new every-time, this is not working.

How can i compare these 2 hashes under given scenario?

**EDIT :**

there was a dynamic timestamp in input because of which there was a difference in hash recieved vc hash generated from params recived.**But**, i am still getting the value as False on comparing `hexdigest`!! :\

Comment: Can you add the exact_value of input1 and input2 to the question? The only way hash outputs can differ is if the input strings are different, and it seems to me you have a parameter whose value is erroneously being changed every time at runtime.

Comment: @mu無 : dude...i hate you!! :p

Comment: I will take your comment to mean that I was right :D Posting the same as an answer.

Comment: @mu無 : i am still getting `False` after removing the dynamic value!

Comment: Add the code pieces. Pretty sure you are using something on the input string which is changing it.

Comment: @mu無 : added edit...there was issue with params but still getting false..suspect something related to `bytes` as suggested in one of the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the exact values of `input1` and `input2` to the question.

The only way hash outputs can differ is if the input strings are different, and it seems to me you have a parameter whose value is erroneously being changed every time at runtime. If I were in your shoes, I would check for some timestamp or request randomnumber etc being fed into the SHA calculation every time, which is different for each request.

**Edit**:

As the OP mentions, this was an issue with a dynamic timestamp being present in the input string. As for using the `bytes` function, it is not really needed for strings and comparing direct `sha512(input).hexdigest` should work.

Answer (score 3):

[secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module in python provides a function, 'compare_digest', which can also be used to compare two 'sha' family hash functions' digests and hexdigests. Here is an example.

```
import hashlib, secrets

data_1 = b'Hello'
sha256_1 = hashlib.sha256(data_1).digest()

data_2 = b'Hello'
sha256_2 = hashlib.sha256(data_2).digest()

data_3 = b'However'
sha256_3 = hashlib.sha256(data_3).digest()

print(secrets.compare_digest(data_1, data_2)) #True
print(secrets.compare_digest(data_1, data_3)) #False
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `input1` is from an API and is a `str`, it needs to be fed into the actual hash function. Looking at the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) we can see that something like

```
...
h1 = hashlib.sha512(bytes(input1))
return h1.digest() == input2.digest()
```

We need to convert `input1` from `str`to `bytes` because the hash function expects an input that is bytes-like. However, depending on your Python version (2.X instead of 3.X) this conversion isn't necessary since strings are `bytes` by default.

Comment: Okay, then you can drop converting the string to a bytes type, and just do something like `h1 = hashlib.sha512(input1)`.

Comment: yup..i need to remove `bytes`!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
if calculated_hash.digest() != input_hash:
    return False
return True
```

But it's difficult to say without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `type` to check your object.

Suppose you are sure that your objects are hash, the expression is definitely correct:

```
input1.digest() == input2.digest()
```

If the object isn't `<type '_hashlib.HASH'>` but it is string, you first should hash the object, and then compare the objects.

```
input1 = hashlib.sha512(input1)
input1.digest() == input2.digest()
```

Comment: `input1` is generated via `hashlib.sha512()` only.Again passing the value to it won't change the hash? Sorry, i have no idea about this, so asked! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor It's just a situation to guess your issue. Except you offer more information or total codes, we never understand your problem. By the way, please note the object type, we can understand more.

Answer (score -1):

What i think this should work:

```
input1 == input2.digest()
```

Because, digest will produce string. And you getting input1 from api that's string.

Demo:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hash =hashlib.sha512("hello")
>>> type(hash)
<type '_hashlib.HASH'>
>>> type(hash.digest())
<type 'str'>
>>> print hash.digest()
?q?$?b?x]??j??=s1??
                    ?????%g<?##?ٛ??|z?n???
                                         FcG\.\:??os???C
>>> hash.hexdigest()
'9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043'
```

## May be you need to use hexdigest().